# Python string sentence removal

Tags: python, string

Im kind of new to python. Im trying to remove the first sentence from a string using the full stop as the delimiter. Is split the right method to be using in this instance? Im not getting the desired result...

```
def get_summary(self):
    if self.description:
        s2 = self.description.split('.', 1)[1]
        return s2
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: Try this:`'. '.join(self.description.split('. ')[1:])`

Comment: @pythonm: Why? The OP is doing it correctly, split only once and get the second element.

Comment: I think it's OK, but you don't have to reference it to a new variable name, just return the value: `return self.description.split('.', 1)[1]`

Comment: If this isn't working for you, something else is wrong. Like there not being any full stops to split on.

Comment: Please show an example of the data you're starting with, the expected result, and the actual result. The code you have should work, although it leaves in a leading space.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you only get the 2nd sentance, without the full-stop symbol, to solve this you can use the join-method for strings. This will combine all elements in the list to 1 string, separated with the string.

```
def get_summary(self):
    if self.description:
        s2 = ".".join(self.description.split('.')[1:])
        return s2
    else:
        return None
```

using [1:] will give you a new element that includes the 2nd element, and all elements after this one in the list.

Answer (score 1):

While `split()` is correct, it is not optimal: it will uselessly split your entire text, and you only want the first occurrence.

Use [`partition()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) that will return you a 3-tuple:

```
first_sentence, separator, the_rest = text.partition('.') # or '. '
# if you don't care about the first sentence, it can be written shorter:
_, _, the_rest = text.partition('.')
```

Note that if there's no separator (full stop) in your text, it will chop off the entire text, and leave you with an empty string. If you'd like to handle this more gracefully, try something like this:

```
def chopFirstSentence(text):
  first_sentence, _, the_rest = text.partition('. ')
  return the_rest or first_sentence
```

This works because if `the_rest` is empty it would evaluate to `False`, and `first_sentence` would be returned then. If `the_rest` is not empty, the calculation of `or` will short-circuiit and immediately return `the_rest`.

Also note that the above algorithm is naïve; it would break on things like "St. Louis" or "Lt. Colonel" or "cf. foo" that obviously do not have embedded sentence breaks. You could rule out most false positives of this kind by checking the last word. Then `find()` / `rfind()` and possibly regular expressions are your friends.